Why does `paste` alter the string output of Sys.time and time.duration?
I'm having a hard time understanding why the {base} paste function in R seems to alter the way it prints certain variables.
start_time <- Sys.time()
result <- sum(1:10000)
dur_time <- Sys.time() - start_time

print(paste(Sys.time(), "duration:", dur_time))
print(Sys.time())
print(dur_time)

which outputs
> print(paste(Sys.time(), "duration:", dur_time))
[1] "2024-10-16 14:46:47.30905 duration: 0.00193095207214355"
> print(Sys.time())
[1] "2024-10-16 14:46:47 CEST"
> print(dur_time)
Time difference of 0.001930952 secs

In other words, print(paste(dur_time)) is very different compared to print(dur_time). The first output is just the value and missing the time unit, meaning when it outputs 0.234 it could be either seconds, minutes or hours, no way to tell, so kind of useless imho.
Also notice how the Sys.Time() output differs, it's either with the timezone or with milliseconds when using paste().
My question is

Why is the output different?
How can I get the output Time difference of 0.001930952 secs while also using the paste function? (or any other output, as long as it includes the timeunit)


If you look at class(Sys.time()), it's classes are  "POSIXct", "POSIXt" for a datetime. It has it's own default print() method, which you get when you print it directly. When you put it in paste(), it's coerced to character class, and the character class conversion includes more information than the default print.
To have full control over how a datetime is coverted to character class, you can use the format function, which has many options documented at ?format.POSIXct.
If you look at the code of the print.POSIXct method, you'll see that the default print uses format(Sys.time(), usetz = TRUE), so that's what you would use if you want to match the print() output.
Similarly, class(dur_time) shows it has class "difftime". The print.difftime method uses (for a single value):
cat("Time difference of ", format(unclass(x), digits = digits), 
        " ", attr(x, "units"), "\n", sep = "")

You could use the code, perhaps simplifying it and making your own wrapper, which you can customize as you like--perhaps deleting the "Time difference of" part.
diff_format = function(x, digits = 3) {
  paste0(
    "Time difference of ",
    format(unclass(x), digits = digits), 
    " ", attr(x, "units")
  )
}

And then use something like this:
paste(format(Sys.time(), usetz = TRUE), "duration:", diff_format(dur_time))
# [1] "2024-10-16 09:18:10 EDT duration: Time difference of 0.536 secs"


Correct, and the difference between two POSIXt objects is a difftime object, and it also has its own print and format functions.

In this simple use case, the most direct way to get what the OP wants might be to explicitly include the units property that paste strips from the difftime object: print(paste(Sys.time(), "duration:", dur_time, units(dur_time)))

Continuing with your example code:
> class(dur_time)
[1] "difftime"
> format(dur_time)
[1] "0.00023818 secs"
> print(dur_time)
Time difference of 0.00023818 secs
> 

Those are the existing methods for difftime.  A common way to work with these is to extract solely the numeric value
> as.numeric(dur_time)
[1] 0.00023818
> print(paste(Sys.time(), "duration:", as.numeric(dur_time)))
[1] "2024-10-16 08:18:38.89727 duration: 0.000238180160522461"
> 

and as was remarked above in a comment, you can also call units(dur_time) which returns the unit attribute of the object. (There are also a pair of setter and getter functions for the unit.)
The key takeaway is that as.numeric() effectively casts your dur_time object to a floating point number. Which is your example is then converted to character, and pasted, as you expect.  A difftime objects injects its custom formatter which is the right thing when you just show it, i.e. dur_time here.

"which is the right thing when you just show it" I'd argue it's not the right thing, because a number without a unit says absolutely nothing

I think you misunderstand my point.  As it is up to you to make the cast and to control when you want a number it cannot be 'accidental'.  Yet sometimes you want to control the formating, maybe round it, convert it etc.  The default, as I explained to you, is text with unit.

Ok agreed but then why does as.character also return just the numeric value, as a chr? I was using it for a log file, to see how much time a function takes, and I ended up using print(paste(dur_time, attr(dur_time, "units"))) but imho that should be the default output when you do str or as.character. I mean if you just want the numeric value, for whatever reason, you can always do as.numeric as you point out.

And btw unfortunately a difftime object also can't be used in combination with format() with a strptime string, like %H:%M:%S :-\

Please remove the -1 then.  I was honestly trying to shed some light on your confusion.  Object-orientation and dispatching on type is different in R, and that is the wall you are hitting.  The difftime object also does not have a format() method respecting strptime formatters; but it all behaves as documented.

Ok but SO won't let me remove the -1 unless the answer is edited. Also, where can I submit an issue to ask that a difftime object could have a format() method that allows strptime formatters?

I will put a token edit in now. Done. Expanded a little.  The bugzilla instance at bugs.r-project.org is one place for feature requests, you could also post to the r-devel list.
